# Pip install from git repository without local files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, easy-install

I am trying to install a python module from a git repository, however it seems that the only way to successfully do this is to add `-e` to the command which leaves behind local files. When I remove the `-e` it says it installs, but I am left without any files and it fails to import. Here is my command:

`pip install -e git+http://gitlab.valk.net/operations/cilib.git#egg=cilib`

Further note, when the `-e` is left off, there is only an `egg-info` file in `site-packages` but not files. Is anyone aware of how you do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to do it this way -- `pip install git+http://gitlab.valk.net/operations/cilib.git` -- without using eggs?  That's how I've installed from github before.

Comment: When I do that, it says it installs correctly, but I am unable to import it. It's really odd. With the `-e` it works great, and I am adding the `--src` tag to put the files away somewhere, it just seems a little janky